# Procedure to update column from function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem.
I need to create a procedure that fetches or_id loop from table1.
This id from table1 is a parameter calling function that returns two values d1 and d2.

The values d1 and d2 must be updated in table1.
How to do it? The function works correctly but I do not know how to loop it.

```
   CURSOR rec_cur IS

       SELECT s.or_id from table1 s;
              id number; 
              a_BASKET_ID varchar(20); 
              a_ORDER_ID varchar (20);

   BEGIN open rec_cur; loop
     fetch rec_cur into number;   
  EXIT WHEN rec_cur%NOTFOUND;    
  SELECT cut(v_param,1,'@') a_BASKET_ID, 
         cut(v_param,2,'@') a_ORDER_ID   
  FROM (SELECT function1(or_id) v_param FROM dual);

  UPDATE table1 b
      SET BASKET_ID = a_BASKETID,
      ORDER_ID = a_ORDERTYPE
      WHERE b.or_id = s.or_id;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: What's the return type of that function? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54328461/edit) your question and add it's defintion.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ugliest codes I've recently seen. Please, for your own sake (as well as ours), learn how to properly format & indent code and make it easier to read and follow.

Furthermore, it is invalid - lacks in `DECLARE`, there's no `END`, you declared some variables (`a_basket_id`, `a_order_id`) but used another ones (`a_basketid`, `a_ordertype`) ... quite a mess.

As of your question: as far as I understood, everything can be done in a single `UPDATE` statement, no PL/SQL is needed:

```
update table1 set
  basket_id = cut(function1(or_id), 1, '@'),
  order_id  = cut(function1(or_id), 2, '@');
```

---

If you insist on PL/SQL, have a look at this: I've used cursor FOR loop as it is simpler to maintain than explicit cursor (as you don't have to create cursor variable(s), open the cursor, worry about exiting the loop, close the cursor - Oracle does it for you). Although you don't need local variables at all (nor PL/SQL, as I've already said), I let them be.

```
declare
  a_basket_id  table1.basket_id%type;
  a_order_id   table1.order_id%type;
begin
  for cur_r in (select or_id from table1) loop
    a_basket_id := cut(function1(cur_r.or_id), 1, '@');
    a_order_id  := cut(function1(cur_r.or_id), 2, '@');

    update table1 set
      basket_id = a_basket_id
      order_id  = a_order_id
      where or_id = cur_r.or_id;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I completely agree with you about the first paragraph :)